# Required suggestions to optimize a piece of unix ksh code

Tags: sed, ksh

I'm new to shell scripting and expecting some guidance on how to optimize the following piece of code to avoid unnecessary loops.

The file "DD.$BUS_DT.dat" is a pipe delimited file and contains 4 columns. Sample data in DD.2015-05-19.dat will be as follows

```
cust portal|10|10|0
sys-b|10|10|0
```

Code

```
i=0;

sed 's///g;s/[0-9]//g' ./DD.$BUS_DT.dat > ./temp-processed.dat
set -A sourceList

while read line
do
        #echo $line
        case $line in
                'cust portal')    sourceList[$i]=custportal;;
                *)              sourceList[$i]=${line};;
        esac        
        (( i += 1));
done < ./temp-processed.dat;

echo ${sourceList[@]};
i=0;
while [[ i -lt ${#sourceList[@]} ]]; do
        print ${sourceList[i]} >> ./processed-$BUS_DT.dat
        (( i += 1))
done
```

My goal is to read the data from the first column of the file without spaces so that the output should be like ...

```
custportal
sys-b
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gone through all your script, but if you just want to get the first column on `|`-separated columns, stripping the spaces that they may have, you can use `awk` like this:

```
$ awk -F"|" '{sub(" ","",$1); print $1}' file
custportal
sys-b
```

This uses `|` as field separator and replaces all the spaces with an empty string. Then, it prints it.